# How to read hive managed table data using spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-shell

I am able to read hive external table using spark-shell but, when I try to read data from hive managed table it only shows column names.

Please find queries here:
[image: Hive queries]
[image: Spark queries]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try using database name as well along with table name?

```
sql(select * from db_name.test_managed)
```

If still result is same, request you to please share output of describe formatted  for both the tables.